# Using both nginx template feature and a reloading solution

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a docker project using both nginx and let's encrypt with certbot.
I'm quite new to docker, and for my nginx image, I'm using the feature that is helping me to use environment variables in nginx configuration.

On a famous tutorial, they use this command to start nginx and reload it automatically

```
command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

The problem is that when I'm using this command instead of the basic one my template is no longer converted to a working nginx conf.

I want to be able to reload nginx but I also want nginx to transform my template in a valid nginx configuration.

How can I achieve that please ?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ADMINER_DESIGN=lucas-sandery
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
      - APP_SECRET=${APP_SECRET}
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@db:3306/${DATABASE_NAME}?serverVersion=5.7
    volumes:
      - ../app:/var/www

  node:
    image: node:alpine
    volumes:
      - ../app:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'yarn install ; yarn run watch'"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ../app:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./logs:/var/log
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - APP_DOMAIN=${APP_DOMAIN}

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

And my site.template.conf file

```
upstream php-upstream {
    server php-fpm:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name ${APP_DOMAIN};

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/${APP_DOMAIN}/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${APP_DOMAIN}/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name ${APP_DOMAIN};
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: doesn't your template file need to end in `.template`? I ask as mine does and I can't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in [this line](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/930c2e26dee0aceca03c9ca7c5686d6c43b26526/entrypoint/docker-entrypoint.sh#L12), `docker-entrypoint.sh` wont trigger if your commands first argument is not `nginx` or `nginx-debug`, and yours is `/bin/bash`.

In order to run entrypoint as well change your command to:
`"/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & /docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `restart: always` in the `docker-compose.yml` `nginx` section to handle service exits by errors, and also if you want to trigger it manually you can issue a `docker-compose restart nginx` in shell at the folder you have the `yml` file.

I don't know if you've intentionally left out of your question sensitive information like `${APP_DOMAIN}`, but if you want to insert these values you can use docker secrets. You can read more about docker secrets here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

(Hint: you don't need to use swarm to have secrets, at the end of this link there is a docker-compose example. As long as you start the services with it you don't need swarm).

#### EDIT

So the issue is you can't substitute environment variables on a nginx conf file. have you seen this: https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration-new-in-119 ?

I found this information here: https://serverfault.com/a/1022249/80400

---

If you want to reload nginx at every 6h, why don't you use a `crontab` ? You can keep everything as it is and do in the crontab:

```
* */6 * * * cd /home/to/docker-compose.yml/ && docker-compose exec nginx -s reload > /var/log/reloading_nginx.log
```

(I think `docker-compose exec` is the right command  instead of `docker-compose run`).

Comment: Thanks for you help. As I posted, the substitution is working if I left the nginx start command unchanged. When I add a command in my docker-compose.yml with a specific script (e.g : reloading nginx every 6 hours) my template doesn't generate my nginx conf. anymore from the template.
If I read the doc : "But this image has a function, which will extract environment variables before nginx starts."
This step is no longer done when I add a custom command in my docker-compose, I would like to be able to specify a custom command to start my nginx AND still substitute my env. vars stored in a .env

Comment: From this link : https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/Dockerfile#L112
It looks like this script is not played when I add a custom command: **20-envsubst-on-templates.sh**

Comment: Thanks, I will try with a crontab (but I heard it's not a good practice for a matter of process)
I will follow this example : https://github.com/jordancrawfordnz/nginx-auto-reload-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile)
But I would like to understand why my entrypoint doesn't work at some point.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi. It's because the 20-ish script is only called when the entrypont is dockerfile-entrypoint.sh.

Comment: I mean, 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh is called inside docker-entrypoint.sh and when you change the entrypoint to your script, it doesn't trigger it. Alright ?

Comment: And by the way, I had no idea of template functionality in nginx before your question, and now I'm already using it it in my current project. Thanks for that :)